# Find how much to rotate given a box and a point A, such that an arbitrary vector within the box points towards point A

Tags: geometry, 3d, rotations

In a 3D world, given a box `B`, a pivot `P`, and a direction vector `V`, how can I find out how much to rotate at `P` such that `V` points towards an arbitrary point `A`?

Problem source:

I am a software developer that come across the need to rotate an object in the above manner, where a 3d model need to be rotated in this way for the user to interact with.

Current Attempts:

I tried using an offset between the direction vector and the pivot, and calculate the rotation required between the offseted target and the pivot.

However all my current attempts is done in code, and I left the mathematical calculation to the libraries due to my limited knowledge - which means to be honest I am not very clear what they actually do.

Note:

1. `B` can be of any arbitrary size,
2. `P` can be anywhere within the box
3. `V` can be anywhere within the box
4. `A` can be anywhere in the world

[An illustration of what I am aiming for in 2D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEGP9.png)

Comment: I think you should add to this post, and discuss either (1) where the problem came from, or (2) what your thoughts are on how to solve it, such as what you've tried, or what you think will work or won't work. If you don't do this, then your question may get closed. If your question is closed, then it won't get answered.

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard oh my bad! I personally have very limited math background, and hence did not want to share my attempts(Besides all of my attempts is done in code and I mostly leave the heavy lifting to the libraries, which means I don't really know what exactly they do).

Comment: But yes I will certainly add where I encounter the problem

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard do you mind verifying the edit and see if the question is up to standard?

Comment: It's not difficult to show that the information you have presented is not sufficient: it matters where $\mathbf{v}$ is in the plane. How do you want to specify that?

Comment: @AdrianKeister I am not entirely sure what you mean, do you mind explaining it a bit further? I think I mentioned `V` can be anywhere within the box `B`

Comment: Would that be helpful if I provide a 3d representation? I thought it will help me understand the problem better in 2d, and then I can expand to 3d myself - but if they are vastly different I can model my question to help everyone(including myself!)

Comment: There is enough information here to solve this, but the main for you to understand is that "how much to rotate" is not quite the right question. In 3D you also have to specify how you are rotating. That is, what axis you are rotating around. Generally, rotations are modelled by either a 3x3 matrix, or (vastly favored by developers), [a quaternion](https://personal.utdallas.edu/~sxb027100/dock/quaternion.html).

Comment: @PaulSinclair: $\mathbf{v}$ could be in one place, you need a clockwise rotation. If it's in another place, but still pointed the same direction with the same length (and therefore the same vector) you could need a counter-clockwise rotation! Without "tacking down" the vector's starting-point, I think there is not enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes, I am currently using a quaterion to do the rotation, however I must admit the libraries I am using abstract a lot the internal calculation for me. I will read up more about quaterion!

Comment: @AdrianKeister - $V$ is a direction vector. It doesn't have a starting point. It merely indicates a direction. You can think of it as "starting" at $P$".

Comment: I think for the purpose of this question, we can assume that all three axis might be involved in the rotation? However if it simplifies the question we can assume we will only rotate on the $x$ axis

Comment: I'm writing up a process for you that goes though determining the quaternion needed step-by-step. The bit I've already written explaining how quaternions add, multiply and divide you can skip since you have a library that surely does it for you. But I'm leaving it in for completeness (maybe someone else will find it useful).

Comment: @AdrianKeister I am not sure how does that affect the question, but to make the question as general as possible, I think we can assume that the direction vector has an arbitrary starting point $S$, where $S$ is also within the box $B$. Or if it simplifies the question we can also assume it starts at $P$?

Comment: @Noobnewbier - what, then, do you mean by "direction vector", if it has to have a starting point? "direction vector" normally means that it indicates a direction, not a place. If $V$ is anything other than just a direction, please let me know, because it changes how things need to be handled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104680/discussion-between-noobnewbier-and-paul-sinclair).

Comment: Paul: V is not a normal direction vector: it is attached to a point in the rectangle, and therefore not movable. Imagine if the top edge of the rectangle were already pointed at A and that V was aligned along that top edge: then you don't have to rotate at all. But if you take that same V and align it along the bottom edge of the rectangle, it would not be pointed at A, and you would have to rotate.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a better way of accomplishing this, but this is one method of calculating the [quaternion of rotation](https://personal.utdallas.edu/~sxb027100/dock/quaternion.html):

We represent everything as a quaternion. That means instead of 3 coordinates, it will have 4, the first of which is $0$. In handling quaternions, addition and multiplication are defined by
$$(a,b,c,d) + (w, x, y, z) = (a + w, b + x, c+y, d + z)$$
$$\begin{align}(a,b,c,d)(w, x, y, z) =\, (&aw - bx - cy - dz, \\&ax + bw + cz - dy, \\&ay - bz + cw + dx, \\&az + by - cx + dw)\end{align}$$Yes, the multiplication formula is a bit of a mess, but you only have to program it once. A real number $t$ is identified with the "scalar" quaternion $(t, 0, 0, 0)$ and a vector $V = (v_1, v_2, v_3)$ is identified with the "vector" quaternion $(0,v_1, v_2, v_3)$. Thus we can say that $$q = (t , v_1, v_2, v_3) = t + v$$where $t$ is the "scalar part of $q$", and $v$ is the "vector part $q$". Quaternions have conjugates defined by negating the vector part: $\bar q = t - v$. You can show that the product $q\bar q$ always has non-negative scalar part, and zero vector part, so we consider it to be just a real number. The absolute value, or norm, of a quaternion is $|q| = \sqrt{q\bar q} = \sqrt{t^2 + v_1^2 + v_2^2 + v_3^2}$. It follows that the inverse of a quaternion $q$ is $$\frac 1q = \frac {\bar q}{q\bar q} = \frac {\bar q}{|q|^2}$$

1. First convert your point/vector information to quaternions with $0$ scalar part: $$P \to (0, P_1, P_2, P_3)\\A \to (0, A_1, A_2, A_3)\\V \to (0, V_1, V_2, V_3)$$
2. We need not $A$, but the vector from $P$ to $A$, which is $N = A- P$. But we are only concerned about direction, not length, so we need a unit vector/quaternion. Divide $N$ by its length to get the target quaternion for the rotation: $T = \frac 1{|N|} N$
3. $V$ is already a vector, so you don't need to subtract $P$ from it. Since you call it a direction vector, I assume it is already a unit vector. If not, divide it by its norm to turn it into a unit vector.
4. We are looking for the rotation that carries $V$ to $T$. Multiply them together and break the result into scalar and vector parts: $VT = d + W$. The real number $d = -\cos \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors $V$ and $T$ (if $V$ and $T$ were not unit vectors, then $d$ would also be multiplied by the product of their lengths). $W$ is a vector perpendicular to both $V$ and $T$ and provides the axis we need to rotate around.
5. If $|W| = 0$, then either $V = T$ or $V = -T$. Which is easily determined by comparing their coordinates. In the first case, you need do nothing, so the quaternion of rotation is just $1 = (1, 0, 0, 0)$. In the second case, it is $-1 = (-1, 0, 0, 0)$. The remainder of this can then be skipped.
6. If $|W| \ne 0$, then let $U = \frac 1{|W|}W$, the unit vector in the same direction.
7. Set $\theta = \arccos d$. You can also use $\theta = \text{atan2}(d, |W|)$, which might be a little more stable (I haven't investigated that, though).
8. The quaternion of rotation will be $$q = \cos\frac \theta 2 + \sin\frac \theta 2 U$$

To rotate an arbitrary *vector* $S$, the result is just $$S' = qSq^{-1}$$ To rotate a point $B$, the process is $$B' = P + q(B - P)q^{-1}$$

Comment: For a sanity check, take the rectangle $(0,0), (1/2,0),(1/2,1),(0,1).$ Let $P$ be the origin, and $A=(1,1).$ Now first suppose that $\mathbf{v}$ has its tail at $(0,1)$ and its head at $(1/2,1)$ so that its vector representation is $(1/2,0).$ The angle of rotation should be zero, since it's already pointed straight at $A.$ Now shift $\mathbf{v}$ to have its tail at the origin, and its head at $(1/2,0).$ Its vector representation is the same, but now it needs a $\pi/4$ counter-clockwise rotation in order to point at $A.$ Does your solution work with this case?

Comment: hi, thanks for answering, I originally intent to respond when I have implemented yours/Adrian's answers and see which one suits my need,
however it is quite impossible lately as I have other priorities. I will update you when I can get back to it

Comment: Not sure why I didn't answer Adrian Keister's comment at the time, but for later readers, let me point out that quaternions work for all three-dimensional rotations. So you have to convert his points to three-dimensions, but other than that, yes, it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most elegant method possible, as it does not provide an exact solution, but it would be close enough for practical purposes. There might be an exact solution, but it is eluding me.

That the point $P$ is anywhere within the box is unimportant, as is the length of the vector $\mathbf{v},$ as is the fact that the vector is inside the box - except for the very important fact that once you have chosen $\mathbf{v},$ it is "tacked down" to that point in the box and is not allowed to move; this is different from a regular vector. The mathematical problem at hand is this: given a rotation point $P$, vector $\mathbf{v}$ with tail at the point $Q,$ and a target point $A,$ find the angle $\theta$ through which and axis $\mathbf{x}$ about which to rotate vector $\mathbf{v}$ such that $\mathbf{v}$ points to $A.$

The first step is to find the axis about which to rotate. The straight-forward answer to this is that if we find the plane containing $\mathbf{v}$ and $A,$ then we want to rotate about an axis perpendicular to that plane and going through the point $P.$ This is not terribly difficult to determine: we use the cross-product to find the appropriate vector. Let $\mathbf{P}$ be the vector to point $P,$ $\mathbf{Q}$ the vector to point $Q,$ and $\mathbf{A}$ the vector to point $A,$ all from the origin. Then the axis of rotation, which we will call $\mathbf{x},$ is given by
$$\mathbf{x}=\frac{\mathbf{v}\times(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{Q})}{\|\mathbf{v}\times(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{Q})\|}, $$
assuming that the angle between $\mathbf{v}$ and $(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{Q})$ is not a multiple of $\pi.$ If the angle is zero, we actually have nothing to do: $\mathbf{v}$ is already pointed to $A!$ if the angle is $\pi,$ then we have the situation that $\mathbf{v}$ is pointed directly away from $A.$ In that case, it doesn't matter what the axis of rotation is, although we still need to find the angle through which to rotate (it isn't necessarily $\pi$). We can let the axis of rotation just be the $x$ axis: $\langle 1,0,0\rangle.$ If the cross product is not zero, then the result is a vector perpendicular to both $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{Q},$ which makes it normal to the plane containing $\mathbf{v}$ and $A.$

Very well, we have the axis about which to rotate the vector $\mathbf{v}:$ in general, it's the line described by the vector $\mathbf{x}$ going through point $P.$

Quaternions have an advantage over rotation matrices for describing rotations: no gimbal lock. They can also handle rotation about arbitrary axes more easily than [rotation matrices](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/rotate/). So we choose quaternions. Here are the relevant points about quaternions: let $\mathbf{u}$ be a unit vector (the rotation axis), and let 
\begin{align*}
r&=\cos(\alpha/2)+\mathbf{u}\sin(\alpha/2)\\
&=\cos(\alpha/2)+\mathbf{i}\,u_x\sin(\alpha/2)+\mathbf{j}\,u_y\sin(\alpha/2)+\mathbf{k}\,u_z\sin(\alpha/2).
\end{align*}
If we take the vector $\mathbf{v}$ and push it into quaternion land $v_q$:
$$v_q=0+\mathbf{i}\,v_x+\mathbf{j}\,v_y+\mathbf{k}\,v_z, $$
then the equation
$v_q'=rv_qr^{-1}$
yields the quaternion version of the vector $\mathbf{v}$ rotated about the axis $\mathbf{u}$ through the angle $\alpha.$

Now then, what follows is an algorithmic method to do the rotation. It turns out that if two vectors are parallel, their cross product is zero, and that fact corresponds to the quaternion representations commuting under quaternion multiplication. That is, $\|\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}\|=0$ if and only if $ab-ba=0.$ Now we expect there to be two angles we could rotate by: one would make $v'$ pointing towards $A,$ and one would make $v'$ pointing away from $A.$ We would need a criterion for between-ness to distinguish between the two; in both cases, $v'(a-q)-(a-q)v'=0.$ So, we just minimize this condition:
$$\min_\alpha\left\|rv_qr^{-1}\!\left(a-rqr^{-1}\right)-\left(a-rqr^{-1}\right)\!rv_qr^{-1}\right\|$$
subject to the condition that the point of $v'$ (which is $r(q+v_q)r^{-1}$) be in-between the tail of $v'$ (which is $rqr^{-1}$) and $A.$ Notice we have to rotate $q$ to $rqr^{-1}$ to make this work.

Just to be clear, $\alpha$ is the rotation angle used to produce $r$ according to the above equation, $a$ is the vector quaternion corresponding to $A,$ $q$ is the vector quaternion corresponding to $Q,$ and $v_q$ is the vector quaternion corresponding to the original $\mathbf{v}$ vector.

You can use this [Stack Exchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328107/how-can-you-determine-a-point-is-between-two-other-points-on-a-line-segment#328122) to determine between-ness.

A slight simplification of the above minimization problem:
$$\min_\alpha\left\|rv_qr^{-1}a-rv_qqr^{-1}-arv_qr^{-1}+rqv_qr^{-1}\right\|. $$

Comment: hi, thanks for answering, I originally intent to respond when I have implemented yours/Paul's answers and see which one suits my need,
however it is quite impossible lately as I have other priorities. I will update you when I can get back to it

Comment: I am sorry about this! I thought I will have the time, but all in a sudden I am having other priorities :(